# How to retrieve all the index() values of particular DOM element in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the index() values of the class name `div.one`  from the parent node descendant hierarchy. Here `div#mydiv` is my parent descendant. 
My Expected result should be in console is : 0,1,2,3,4,5.

JS:

```
$('#mydiv .one').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).index()); // Here Result is 0,1,2,0,1,2 ,but I want 0,1,2,3,4,5
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
     <div class="div-demo">
        <div class="one" >
           Demo 1
        </div>
        <div class="one" >
           Demo 2
        </div>
        <div class="one" >
          Demo 3
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="div-demo">
       <div class="one" >
           Demo 4
        </div>
        <div class="one" >
           Demo 5
        </div>
        <div class="one" >
          Demo 6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/gzdh87y2/

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variant of `index()` will return the index of the element based on its siblings.

You can cache the `one` and use it to get the index of the element in the element set

```
var $ones = $('#mydiv .one');
$ones.each(function() {
  console.log($ones.index(this)); // Here Result is 0,1,2,0,1,2 ,but I want 0,1,2,3,4,5
});
```

or use the index argument of the `each()` callback

```js
$('#mydiv .one').each(function(idx) {
  snippet.log(idx); // Here Result is 0,1,2,0,1,2 ,but I want 0,1,2,3,4,5
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="div-demo">
    <div class="one">
      Demo 1
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      Demo 2
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      Demo 3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="div-demo">
    <div class="one">
      Demo 4
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      Demo 5
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      Demo 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a selector to `index()` which restricts the elements it searches through. Try this:

```
$('#mydiv .one').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).index('.one'));
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gzdh87y2/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Try to invoke the `.index()` over the element collection by passing the `this` object,

```
var cache = $('#mydiv .one');
cache.each(function () {
    console.log(cache.index(this));
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gzdh87y2/4/)

Comment: நன்றி @Rajaprabu Aravindasamy

Comment: @EverGreen மகிழ்ச்சி!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the eq() function and replace index(). 
Example:

```
$('#mydiv .one').each(function () {console.log($(this).eq());});
```